# How to export/import data from/to datagridview to a Excel file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I am using **Microsoft Office 2007** and **Visual studio 2010**.

I want to save data of DataGridView into Excel file once I click the button on Windows form.

Also I want to load data from Excel file into DataGridView by clicking a button.

Pls help...I am very new to VB so unable to write code. Plsss help..

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather big question and there's any number of solutions.

1) Writing to Excel.. There are 3 common ways to do this, 1) Write the data out as CSV format and Excel will happily read it. 2) Use Excel Interop to create a Workbook and write a work sheet to it. This requires that Excel is installed and 3) Use OleDB to create an Excel.

2) Reading Excel... Again you can use Excel Interop to read Excel Workbooks and again you need Excel installed, and you can also use OleDB to read Excel files.

There are other ways, but these are the most commonly used ones.

On balance I would approach this by using OleDB in the first instance and there's lots of examples on StackOverflow on how to read and write to Excel.

If you need access to all of Excel's formatting or charting facilities then you will need Interop. It's relatively easy to use and again there's lots of examples of how to do it.

EDIT:

At it's most simple...

First add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel under the project properties, then...

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class frmExcelExport

    Private Sub frmExcelExport_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dgvDataToExport.Columns.Add("C1", "Column 1")
        dgvDataToExport.Columns.Add("C2", "Column 2")
        dgvDataToExport.Rows.Add("Col1-Row1", "Col2-Row1")
        dgvDataToExport.Rows.Add("Col1-Row2", "Col2-Row2")

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application

        xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Example_Export"

        For nRow = 0 To dgvDataToExport.Rows.Count - 1

            For nCol = 0 To dgvDataToExport.Columns.Count - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(nRow + 1, nCol + 1) = dgvDataToExport.Rows(nRow).Cells(nCol).Value
            Next nCol

        Next nRow

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Example.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
                           Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges)

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

    End Sub

End Class
```

But, really there's massive amounts of stuff on this all over the internet. This is simply adding to it

Comment: Thanks :-) Can you please give me a simple code to export a row from datagrid to excel using Excel Interop so that i will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). You can find lots of examples around the internet. E.g. there is nice [summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx) on MSDN. Or take a look on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML).